# Node.js: trouble with listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, listener

I'm developing my first app in Node.js and I think I don't understand correctly yet how  listener works, because the example that I wrote doesn't show what I thought it was going to show.

I want to use a module (msfnode) which is a metasploit RPC client, so it connects through websockets.

I made a class and the constructor has this code:

```
this.clientmsf = new MetasploitClient({
            login : options.login || 'myLogin',
            password : options.password || 'myPassword'
        });
        this.clientmsf.on('connected',function(err,token) {
            if (err) throw err; 
        });
```

So I thought I could use the object "clientmsf" in other function of that class and it shows an error:   error_message: 'Invalid Authentication Token'. THis is the code:

```
this.clientmsf.exec(['console.create'], function(err,r){
            consoleID = r.id;
            console.log(r);
        });
```

I think I have this error because I don't know all concepts of node.js so I will be very appreciate if someone helps me.

Thank you very much.

PD. This is an example of msfnode library:

```
var metasploitClient = require('metasploitJSClient');
var onConnect = function(err,token) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.error_message);
        process.exit(0);
    }
    metasploitVersion();
}
var metasploitVersion = function() {
    // Do not care about token, it will automaticaly
    // be added as the second arguments
    // The first value of the array is the function
    // you want to call. Full list is available
    // in metasploit remote api documentation
    var args = ['core.version'];
    client.exec(args,function(err,r) {
        if (err) return console.log('Error: '+err);
        console.log('-> Version: '+r);
    });
}
var client = new metasploitClient({
    login:'myLogin',
    password:'myPassword',
});
client.on('connected',onConnect);
```

Error:

```
{ error: true,
  error_class: 'Msf::RPC::Exception',
  error_string: 'Msf::RPC::Exception',
  error_backtrace: 
   [ 'lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:148:in `process\'',
     'lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:90:in `on_request_uri\'',
     'lib/msf/core/rpc/v10/service.rb:72:in `block in start\'',
     'lib/rex/proto/http/handler/proc.rb:38:in `call\'',
     'lib/rex/proto/http/handler/proc.rb:38:in `on_request\'',
     'lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:363:in `dispatch_request\'',
     'lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:297:in `on_client_data\'',
     'lib/rex/proto/http/server.rb:157:in `block in start\'',
     'lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:48:in `call\'',
     'lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:48:in `on_client_data\'',
     'lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:192:in `block in monitor_clients\'',
     'lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:190:in `each\'',
     'lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:190:in `monitor_clients\'',
     'lib/rex/io/stream_server.rb:73:in `block in start\'',
     'lib/rex/thread_factory.rb:22:in `call\'',
     'lib/rex/thread_factory.rb:22:in `block in spawn\'',
     'lib/msf/core/thread_manager.rb:100:in `call\'',
     'lib/msf/core/thread_manager.rb:100:in `block in spawn\'' ],
  error_message: 'Invalid Authentication Token',
  error_code: 401 }
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is the code I checked:

```
clientmsf.on('connected',function(err,token) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    var consoleID;
    console.log('token:' + token);
    // should have connected by now
    clientmsf.exec(['console.list'], function(err,r){
        consoleID = r;
        console.log(r);
    });
    console.log (consoleID);
});
```

And this is what it shows:

```
token:[object Object]
undefined
{ consoles: [ { id: '0', prompt: 'msf > ', busy: false } ] }
```

Comment: Is this the entire error message that you are receiving as usually node gives you the line number where the error occured? And have you actually launched msfrpcd on the machine?

Comment: No, the error is from Metasploit API. I think it's possible that the trouble is a "race condition" because "exec" is executed before connect and the object don't know the token yet. I'm going to add the full error.

Thank Vasil for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how in the sample code they do the work (metasploitVersion) only after connecting and getting a token.

```
var onConnect = function(err,token) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.error_message);
        process.exit(0);
    }
    // in the connect callback here - you have a token
    // only then call to do the work
    metasploitVersion();
}
```

Try moving  your 'this.clientmsf.exec' code inside the connect callback function.  If you have it outside that callback, it will execute before the connect is done.

I would also recommend that you log out the token inside that callback to ensure you're connected properly.

I'm suggesting something like:

```
var clientmsf = new MetasploitClient({
    login : options.login || 'myLogin',
    password : options.password || 'myPassword'
});

clientmsf.on('connected',function(err,token) {
    if (err) throw err; 

    console.log('token:' + token);
    // should have connected by now
    clientmsf.exec(['console.create'], function(err,r, token){
        consoleID = r.id;
        console.log(r);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did that but then I had a question, How can I do it if I want to execute "exec" more than once? Thank you bryanmac.

Comment: Error:

TypeError: Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/dani/proyectos_eclipse/tfg-pentesting/lib/msfManager.js:71:25)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at msapi.onAuthLogin (/home/dani/proyectos_eclipse/tfg-pentesting/node_modules/msfnode/metasploitJSClient.js:65:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/dani/proyectos_eclipse/tfg-pentesting/node_modules/msfnode/metasploitJSClient.js:41:24)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

Comment: OK - you're at the next issue.  in JS, 'this' would be the function it's in.  So, you need to declare clientmsf as a var.  Updated code snippet.  (remember I can't see your line numbers)

Comment: Hello again Bryanmac, I edited the first post. As you can see, consoleID is undefined.

Comment: check err and log it.  if (err) console.log(err.message)

Comment: It shows the same...so there aren't errors.   

`clientmsf.exec(['console.list'], function(err,r){
           if (err) console.log(err.message);
             consoleID = r;
             console.log(r);
         });`